# SSH implementation for cmd.exe

Tags: windows, remote-access, ssh, command-line

Is there an SSH2 implementation that will run in the Win32 console (i.e. cmd.exe)?

As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong) I know of the following SSH implementations:

- PuTTY - Doesn't run in the Win32 console
- TeraTerm SSH - Doesn't run in the Win32 console
- SecureCRT - Exorbitant pricing, doesn't run in the Win32 console
- SSH via Cygwin - Enormous dependency

Comment: Cygwin's SSH does run in the Win32 console.

Comment: You can also try `plink` which comes with putty. The console support is... very limited (speak: non-existant) - it won't support any ansi-escape sequences, but if you don't need them, it might be enough.

Comment: SSH comes as a dependency to Git for windows. It comes with a hole suit of POSIX style tools that run under windows nativly via MinGW. MinGW is arguably a lighter and a more 'Native' choice over Cygwin. Also the Git installer is only ~20MB and easy to install.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/):

- free
- works withing cmd
- supports SSH2
- also provides SSH server functionality

[image]

Comment: How could you possibly be recommending security-related software like ssh that hasn't been updated since mid 2004, just a couple of months short of 10 years?

Comment: The OP just wants the client. What kind of security issues are you fearing with a client?

Comment: Why would security be of any less concern if it's the client?  Older PuTTY versions do suffer from several security issues, for example.

Comment: @cnst Most attacks concern servers, SSH clients are pretty safe (a bit less if you connect to some rogue servers): http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/changes.html

Comment: That only depends on who's doing the attack; NSA and GCHQ is likely more interested (and capable) in attacking the clients than just the servers.  From the page you've linked, `arbitrary code execution on the client by a malicious SSH-2 server before host key verification, has been fixed`, http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/vuln-ssh2-debug.html, is exactly the kind of attack (from late 2004, no less) allowing anyone with control of your internet pipe to own you easily.  Can you confirm that the unofficial **mid-2004** port of OpenSSH for Windows is safe from similar?

Comment: I don't know: most of the time I connect to non-malicious servers.

Comment: And how could you be sure the server you're connecting to is not malicious?

Comment: Private OpenStack network. Not saying it is 100% secure, nothing is, but I still manage to sleep. Anyway at this point I guess as you say we (I leave it to the OP) should check out the OpenSSH client's security issues since 2004 and let the OP decided if it represents a danger to him. OpenSSH for Windows gets ~500 downloads/day on SF, so it is still pretty commonly used.

Answer (score 5):

Not Sure if this is off topic but... 
There is a windows cmd wrapper called ConEmu that supports tabs and allows you to putty windows into those tabs:

Starting a putty instance with the -new_console argument hook
[image: Starting a putty instance with the -new_console argument hook]

Putty GUI comes up, can be avoided with proper arguments passed on the first step.
[image: Putty GUI comes up, can be avoided with proper arguments passed on the first step.]
Putty console is new a tab in the ConEmu Window (note the screen splitting is caused by ":s" in "-new_console:s
[image: Putty console is new a tab in the ConEmu Window (note the screen splitting is caused by ":s" in "-new_console:s]

Answer (score 4):

There is a ssh executable present in each git installation. The location may change by version, but it should be present. Note that the ssh executable will not be in your PATH by default after installing git, so it won't work from commandline just like that.

Instead of adding the folder to my PATH (that would add many executables, which I want to avoid), I use a script `ssh.bat` which is located in a folder on my PATH.

```
REM Note: this was the path for Git 2.6.2
REM the @ prevents the command being shown twice in the cmd window
REM %* forwards all parameters
@"c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" %*
```

Comment: I like this answer but Git is simply using MSYS here.  And, if you are careful (e.g. using Dependency Walker), you can extract what you need directly from MSYS without having to install Git or MSYS.

Comment: You can also just use a bat script to add "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" to the Path var, then `ssh.exe` will be called directly with `ssh`. `set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%`

Answer (score 4):

I needed this for a cross-platform project.  And since none of the other answers precisely solved the problem for me, I went ahead and built it:

32-bit ssh.exe:  https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ssh-win32

64-bit ssh.exe:  https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ssh-win64

Answer (score 3):

The [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe) version of PuTTY is a console application that can be run from `cmd`.

Comment: Welcome to SR. Link only answers are not acceptable quality; please update to include *why* **you** are recommending this/comment on stability/some more details.

Comment: I think this is an appropriate answer. plink is a good solution to this problem, but it looks like it was meant to process scrips, not provide a user interface to SSH. I cant figure out how to make any visual controls work in it (e.g. irssi)