# SSH and Telnet Client

Tags: network-monitor, ssh, telnet

Whilst [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) may support partial or all of my requirements, I have not gone through and looked at configuring it (and if it is valid, feel free to document it here for me). Essentially I am after a software solution (and I am willing to pay for the software if it is a one-time payment) that are able to:

- Runs on Windows 7/8/10, Windows Server 2003/2008/2012
- Runs via a Citrix XenApp Deployment
- Stores configuration (or session) files in a custom directory (a shared network path in this instance)

To better elaborate on the configuration files, I want to be able to:

- Store connection settings (SSH/Telnet, Host Name and IP) for multiple users
- Store login scripts/commands against SSH sessions
- Load sessions from another instance and reference the files on the shared path (I know PuTTY you can export from registry keys or write to a directory)

Additional preferences:

- Output logs of user input, such as commands run on a switch
- Allows shortcuts on desktop, e.g. "C:\Program Files\Program\launch.exe" -example.session

In relation to the system requirements, obvioulsly the more lightweight the better (I think this is one of the main reasons PuTTY is so popular) but also:

- Little external (if ANY) requirements, such as .NetFramework (a pure example, people..)

There are some related questions I'm currently checking out. I see some features available, but none matching them entirely:

- [SSH implementation for cmd.exe](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3000/185)
- [Command-line SSH/SCP client command for windows (not cygwin)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27703/185)
- [Open-source SSH terminal client for Windows with tabs, private key auth + more](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1543/185)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about *all* your requirements, but I would recommend to look deeper into [ZOC SSH Client](https://www.emtec.com/ssh/ssh-client.html). I have used it in the past (still occasionally) and I can confirm a few of your requirements:

- running on 7/8/10 (per their [feature page](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/features.html))
- you can choose a custom data folder on their installer
- has an extensive directory of hosts with stored password or scripts
  (the directory is a single file, I often copied it between laptop and PC via File > Show Data Folder)
- generally superb scripting support
- logfiles for sessions (also debug logs)
- command-line parameters for nearly every thing
- can also create quick launch icons on the desktop from host directory

[image]

[image]